# Parse Comma(,) String in MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, string, type-conversion

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE lead_to_loan(xReffID_list text)
```

I want to use this `xReffID_list` variable in a select statement as

```
SELECT * FROM XXXX where xreffID IN (xReffID_list);
```

but the xreffID  is a `int` Variable

How Can I use `xReffID_list text` which is a string of comma separated numbers in the `IN`condition for  `int` variables ?

Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS lead_to_loan$$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE lead_to_loan(XRefID_list text) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE loanCount int(11) default 0;
DECLARE matchCount int(11) default 0;
DECLARE loan_XRefID int(11); 
DECLARE loan_LEADS360ID int(11); 
DECLARE loan_email varchar(100); 
DECLARE loan_phone varchar(30); 
DECLARE loan_cellphone varchar(20); 
DECLARE loan_workphone varchar(20); 
DECLARE loan_closeDate datetime;
DECLARE loan_FundedDate datetime;

DECLARE lead_id int(11);
DECLARE lead_RefId varchar(100); 
DECLARE lead_Email varchar(100); 
DECLARE lead_DayPhone varchar(50); 
DECLARE lead_EveningPhone varchar(20); 
DECLARE lead_Cellphone varchar(20); 
DECLARE lead_DateAdded  varchar(30);

DECLARE done boolean default false;
DECLARE startTime datetime;

DECLARE cursor_loanDetail CURSOR FOR
    SELECT XRefID,LEADS360ID,email,phone,cellphone,workphone,closeDate,FundedDate 
        FROM fsbcorponline.view_loandetail where find_in_set(XRefID, XRefID_list) > 0;

DECLARE cursor_loanMatchLeads CURSOR FOR
SELECT id,RefId,Email,DayPhone,EveningPhone,Cellphone,DateAdded 
            FROM fsbcorponline.leads360leads 
            WHERE RefId !="" AND RefId IS NOT NULL AND  RefId =loan_LEADS360ID AND loan_LEADS360ID>0 OR
            Email !="" AND Email IS NOT NULL AND Email =loan_email OR
            DayPhone !="" AND DayPhone IS NOT NULL AND DayPhone = loan_workphone OR
            EveningPhone !="" AND EveningPhone IS NOT NULL AND EveningPhone= loan_phone OR  
            Cellphone !="" AND Cellphone IS NOT NULL AND Cellphone =loan_cellphone;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

set startTime = now();

    OPEN cursor_loanDetail;
    cursor_loanDetail_loop: loop
        fetch cursor_loanDetail into loan_XRefID,loan_LEADS360ID,loan_email,loan_phone,loan_cellphone,loan_workphone,loan_closeDate,loan_FundedDate;
        if done then
            set done = false;
            leave cursor_loanDetail_loop;
        END if;
        SET loanCount = loanCount+1;

            OPEN cursor_loanMatchLeads;
            cursor_loanMatchLeads_loop: loop
                fetch cursor_loanMatchLeads into lead_id,lead_RefId,lead_Email,lead_DayPhone,lead_EveningPhone,lead_Cellphone,lead_DateAdded;
                if done then
                    set done = false;
                    leave cursor_loanMatchLeads_loop;
                END if;

            SET matchCount = matchCount+1;
            INSERT INTO `fsbcorponline`.`leads_to_loan`(`lead_id`,`lead_RefId`,`lead_Email`,`lead_DayPhone`,`lead_EveningPhone`,`lead_Cellphone`,`lead_DateAdded`,`loan_XRefID`,`loan_LEADS360ID`,`loan_email`,`loan_phone`,`loan_cellphone`,`loan_workphone`,`loan_closeDate`,`loan_FundedDate`)
                   VALUES(lead_id,lead_RefId,lead_Email,lead_DayPhone,lead_EveningPhone,lead_Cellphone,lead_DateAdded,loan_XRefID,loan_LEADS360ID,loan_email,loan_phone,loan_cellphone,loan_workphone,loan_closeDate,loan_FundedDate)
                    ON duplicate key update loan_updateCount = loan_updateCount +1 ;
            leave cursor_loanMatchLeads_loop;
            END loop cursor_loanMatchLeads_loop;
            CLOSE cursor_loanMatchLeads;



    END loop cursor_loanDetail_loop;
    close cursor_loanDetail;
INSERT INTO `fsbcorponline`.`log`(`processName`,`pageName`,`path`,`status`,`note`,`processStartTime`,`processEndTime`)
VALUES('Store Procedure','Lead_to_Loan','Database','1',CONCAT('Loan Matches ',matchCount,' of total ',loanCount),startTime,now());
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Don't use `IN()`, use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: If it isn't absolutely necessary that you store this as a single text list, consider [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data.

Comment: In my database `xReffID` is a int. but this is the requirement user will pass `N` numbers comma seprated so i have to process all that records. am i clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_in_set` to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM XXXX WHERE find_in_set(xreffID, xreffID_list) > 0
```

Comment: tht will select all the records with the numbers in `xreffID_list` ?

Comment: thanks man... but i am still having problem with my store procedure i will paste the code above if you can help?

Comment: What problem are you having?  Is there an error or it just isn't performing as expected?

Comment: problem is the that some times the `cursor_loanDetail_loop` is executed just one time I don't why? as i can find the `loanCount` =1 but i am passing at least 50 id at a time

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cursors as you are using them, I'm afraid.  Can you verify that the initial query does pull 50 rows (or one for each id in the list)?  If it does, then you may want to open a separate question about this.

Comment: thanks for the help man.I got it working there was some problem with my input.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use cast() function available with Mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Hope this will help you.

Comment: cast will not work in my case because its a comma seprated string